# What to call the lump on skin from mosquito bite?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word can I use to describe the small lump on the skin seen after a mosquito bite?

Comment: Usually *itchy* and/or *annoying*.

Comment: Assuming there really is a word, the question is, can you actually **use** it? I'd not understand it if you did, without rushing for a glossary of medical terms myself.

Comment: There really is a word, and lots of people would understand it. http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_do_mosquito_bites_form_bumps; http://www.mosquitoworld.net/mosquitobites.php; http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/life/zoology/insects-arachnids/mosquito3.htm; http://www.wisegeek.com/why-do-mosquitoes-bite.htm

Comment: @JLG Lots of people = many English speakers on the globe?

Comment: Wouldn't the term "Rash" qualify?

Comment: See also: **[Why is it a mosquito *bite*?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120572)**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Technical terms aside, the most common phrase used to describe this is just *mosquito bite*.

> I got a mosquito bite yesterday. It really itches.

Comment: Or, _bug bite_ (esp. when the source is unknown, i.e., it could be from a mosquito, spider, or chigger).

Comment: Itching skeeter bites just makes ’em worse. :)

Comment: Bugs don't bite. Ask any bugger. They sting, prick, pierce, pincer, ..., but not bite.

Comment: @user20908, they may not actually bite, but that doesn't change what we call them.

Comment: *Wheal* is really not a "technical" term; it's in standard dictionaries, with "a small swelling on the skin, as from an insect bite, that usually itches or burns" as the first definition. And, besides, the OP asked for a term for the lump *resulting from* a mosquito bite.

Comment: @JLG, *wheal* may be in general dictionaries, but it's still a "technical term" in the sense that many English speakers don't know the word and wouldn't understand it if you used it. I'm a well-educated adult native speaker, and *I* had never heard the word before I read your answer.

Comment: What then does change the way we call it? A new dictionary entry? re-education?

Comment: @user20908, re-education, maybe? If you can get the majority of speakers to use something other than "mosquito bite" as the default term for this, then the correct answer will change. Until then, "mosquito bite" is what we call it.

Comment: Some will resist still.

Comment: @Kris: [***bite*** has many overlapping senses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bite). Everybody I know would use *bite* to describe a creature puncturing part of their body with its mouthparts to commence feeding on them.

Comment: @hippietrail I'm not biting that! :)

Answer (score 11):

It is a [wheal:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wheal)

> A small swelling on the skin, as from an insect bite, that usually itches or burns.

---

Note: It is not just a technical/medical term; see these websites that also use the word:

[Wiki.answers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_do_mosquito_bites_form_bumps)

[Mosquito World](http://mosquitoworld.net/mosquitobites.php)

[How Stuff Works](http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/life/zoology/insects-arachnids/mosquito3.htm)

[Wise Geek](http://wisegeek.com/why-do-mosquitoes-bite.htm)

Comment: Wheal is archaic - weal is the common spelling.

Comment: @OptimalCynic, What is your source, please? In my *Dorland's Medical Dictionary,* 30th edition, and *Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary*, 2nd edition, *wheal* is the only spelling given. These are both current dictionaries. Also, the link I provided, lists *weal* as an alternate spelling. *Wheal* is not listed as archaic.

Comment: I always thought it was *wheal* too. The OED2 has **† wheal**, *n.¹* meaning “A pimple, pustule.” marked as obsolete, with its last citation from 1707 “When she scratched the little Pimples or Wheals that arose on its surface.” But **wheal** *n.²* is current: “2.  In modern medical use, a flat, usually circular, hard elevation of the skin, esp. that characteristic of urticaria.” Its etymology is listed as “Misspelt form of **weal** *n.²* Compare **wheal** *v.²”* This does all seem connected to a **welt**, but the OED has no definition of that word that matches my own use of it. ***Huh!?***

Comment: Of **weal** *n.²* the OED says of its etymology “A mod. variant of wale n.1, by confusion with **wheal** *n.¹* a pustule: see **wheal** *n.²”* and gives its meaning as “The mark or ridge raised on the flesh by the blow of a rod, lash, etc.; = **wale** *n.¹* 2, **wheal** *n.²”* For pronunciations, **weal** is given as `/wiːl/` and **wheal** as `/hwiːl/`. I can’t find a **welt** `/wɛlt/` with the **weal** sense. Whatever can I be thinking?

Comment: Urticaria is basically hives; the entries for urticaria in both the Saunders and Dorland's dictionaries use the term "wheal" in the definition. From Dorland's: "urticaria: a vascular reaction, usually transient, involving the upper dermis...marked by the development of wheals." *Urticaria* is a technical/medical term; *wheal* is really not.

Answer (score 4):

I would call this a *[welt](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/welt)*.  My impression is that this word is reasonably common and would be readily understood, much more so than *weal*.

Oddly, as tchrist pointed out in a comment on another answer, the OED doesn't really have this definition.  The closest seems to be **welt**, *n.<sup>1</sup>* definition 4c: *A ridge on the flesh, esp. the mark of a healed wound; a seam.*  Could this be a British-American divide?  (I'm a native American English speaker.)

Answer (score 3):

A rather general way to describe any such skin protrusion is a *swelling*.

Comment: There may or may not be a swelling *around* the site of the 'bite' -- it's note the same as the 'bite'.

Answer (score 0):

If the pain and itching are gone and the swelling minimal, then the term "bite-mark" would be what my dialect would dictate.

Comment: I would say that 'bite-mark' suggests that teeth impressions would be visible, such as if you'd been bitten by a person. For bug bites, I would simply say 'bite'.